# In typescript, can a function be typed to return a particular instance?

Tags: typescript

In typescript I would like to have a function, like

`getMin<T>(a: T, b: T): T`

Which will return either a, or b such that, if a < b

`getMin(a, b) === a`

Is always true. For example, the following function would **not** qualify:

```
const getMin = (a: IUser, b: IUser): IUser => {
  if (min(a.userId, b.userId) === a) {
    return new User(a); // copy constructor
  } else {
    return new User(b);
  }
}
```

Because `getMin(a, b) === a` will return `false` since `a` is not referentially equal to the return value of `getMin`. This is because `getMin` returns a copy of `a`, not the `a` that was passed into the function. What I want is a function that returns either of its inputs, something like,

```
const getMin = (a: IUser, b: IUser) => {
  if (min(a.userId, b.userId) === a) {
    return a; // reference
  } else {
    return b;
  }
}
```

That way, if I wrote a function that was accidentally creating a copy when I wanted it to return one of the given references, it would be a compile time error. I'm imagining a type signature like,

`getMin<T>(a: T, b: T): a | b`

Similar to how we can do,

`getThreeOrFive (): 3 | 5`

It seems like the `this` keyword already works this way in TS, since I can write a function like,

`this.doSomething = (): this => { /* does something */ return this }`

Is there some way to do this in TS?

Comment: So you want the function signature to enforce that a copy is going on in the implementation ?

Comment: No no, the opposite! I want the signature to enforce that the return value is referentially equal to one of the inputs.

Comment: I've edited my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you want to guarantee that one of the inputs is returned as the output - not just a matching type.

I don't believe a type system can do this for you, but a good unit test can.

I have written the test without a framework for demonstration purposes - but you can see that a unit test around this would prevent a new instance from being returned:

```
interface IUser {
    userId: number;
}

class User implements IUser {
    userId: number;
    constructor(u: IUser) { 
        this.userId = u.userId;
    }
}

const getMinA = (a: IUser, b: IUser): IUser => {
    if (a.userId < b.userId) {
        return new User(a); // copy constructor
    } else {
        return new User(b);
    }
}


const getMinB = (a: IUser, b: IUser): IUser => {
    if (a.userId < b.userId) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}

const a = new User({ userId: 1 });
const b = new User({ userId: 2 });

if (getMinA(a, b) === a) {
    // Okay
} else {
    alert('getMinA: Not original A');
}

if (getMinB(a, b) === a) {
    // Okay
} else {
    alert('getMinB: Not original A');
}
```

The output from this is:

> getMinA: Not original A

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Are you sure that a type system can't do this? I feel like it can... but I'm curious to know why you think one can't.

Comment: @Ziggy Not sure about 'a type system' but the typescript type system can't

Comment: Type systems deal with types. A system that performed this check would need to analyse the application to infer whether the same reference would be returned. In this example, that can be done against a single method, but imagine trying to track the reference at compile time across multiple calls. It is theoretically possible, but it would be impressive. I would call such a system a "reference system", not a "type system".

Comment: If there was a type annotation for it, then we wouldn't need to trace the reference through the program, because each well typed function would either return that ref or not. So if `f` returns one of its arguments `a` by reference, and `f` calls `g` which doesn't with `a`, then that would be a compile time error. No need to descend into `g`, because we know the return type of `g`. If `f` calls `h` which returns its argument by ref, then we know that the return type of `h(a)` is still `a`.

Comment: But I didn't ask whether it's possible in general: I asked whether it's possible in typescript. If you know that it isn't, and you express that in your answer, I could accept your answer.

Comment: Furthermore, doesn't inferring the type of a function always require you to descend into each function that isn't explicitly typed? Like if `f` has no explicit return value, and it calls `g` with no explicit return value, and returns the return value of `g`... then the only way to know the type of `f` is to determine the type of `g` by inference, which may require you to track the type at compile time across multiple calls?

Comment: We're definitely getting into territory where I have no idea what I'm talking about though: I've never worked on such a system, only used them. If you are a type guru talking from a position of expertise please let me know that I'm wrong!